# How is rrdtool PDP value calculated?

Tags: rrdtool

When I create a RRD database and update it with a GAUGE value 100, then value of the PDP `value` is set to 26.877900000. When I create a RRD database roughly a second later, then PDP `value` is 17.477500000:

```
usr@PC:~$ rm foo.rrd; rrdtool create foo.rrd --start 'N' --step '300' 'DS:RTT:GAUGE:600:0:1000000' 'RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:1440'; rrdtool update foo.rrd N:100; rrdtool dump foo.rrd | grep --color -E '<value>[0-9]+|<unknown_sec>|<lastupdate>'
        <lastupdate>1551973741</lastupdate> <!-- 2019-03-07 17:49:01 EET -->
                <value>2.6877900000e+01</value>
                <unknown_sec> 241 </unknown_sec>
usr@PC:~$ rm foo.rrd; rrdtool create foo.rrd --start 'N' --step '300' 'DS:RTT:GAUGE:600:0:1000000' 'RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:1440'; rrdtool update foo.rrd N:100; rrdtool dump foo.rrd | grep --color -E '<value>[0-9]+|<unknown_sec>|<lastupdate>'
        <lastupdate>1551973742</lastupdate> <!-- 2019-03-07 17:49:02 EET -->
                <value>1.7477500000e+01</value>
                <unknown_sec> 242 </unknown_sec>
usr@PC:~$
```

How is this PDP `value` calculated? My guess is that first time the `rrdtool update foo.rrd N:100` happened 268.779ms later than `rrdtool create`. And second time the `rrdtool update foo.rrd N:100` happened 174.775ms later than `rrdtool create`. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**value** contains `rate*seconds` which occurred up to the last run.

Dump implementation here: [rrd_dump.c](https://github.com/oetiker/rrdtool-1.x/blob/8be9cfd2ebd9bfce5d9fbfee168e82750ade45dc/src/rrd_dump.c#L188)

```
            CB_FMTS("\t\t<value>%0.10e</value>\n",
                rrd.pdp_prep[i].scratch[PDP_val].u_val);
```

Description of `pdp_prep[].scratch[PDP_val].u_val` you can find here: [rrd_update.c#L1689](https://github.com/oetiker/rrdtool-1.x/blob/7bc84418346020b5557ce04ba52720c75efc043c/src/rrd_update.c#L1689)

```
    /* in pdp_prep[].scratch[PDP_val].u_val we have collected
       rate*seconds which occurred up to the last run.
```